# How to adjust row height in datagrid at runtime in C# .net?

Tags: c#, datagrid

How to adjust row height in datagrid at runtime in C# .net?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the rows and change it, for example:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    row.Height -= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

other than loop this event can be used for setting row height in WPF grid.

private void dataGrid1_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)

```
    {
        e.Row.Height = 100.00;
    }
```